# React-Typescript pass dynamic value to sibling?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dynamic

Hi kind of new to coding and React (~3 weeks in) so if I asked this question in a weird way please let me know and I will try to clarify as best as I can.

I am working on these two components and I wanted to pass data that is generated dynamically  from COMPONENT1 to COMPONENT2 (see code below).

In COMPONENT1 I am using map to dynamically display an array of buttons. Then using JSX to dynamically add the text in based on the data of an array of objects that was defined. This works fine but what I wanted to do is to take some of the data that was dynamically rendered and pass it on to COMPONENT2 i.e. so each button can send there particular data down to COMPONENT2.

In particular, I want to be able to send obj.text dynamically to COMPONENT2 based on which button I press.

COMPONENT 1

```
export default function Button(props){
 const arrObj = [
   { id: '0', var: 'varString1', text: 'textString1'},
   { id: '1', var: 'varString2', text: 'textString2'}
 ]

 return (
  <div>
   {arrObj.map( (item) =>
    <div key={obj.id}>
     <Icon> {`${obj.var}`}<span> {`${obj.text`}</span></Icon>
     <Button>{'add something'}</Button>
    </div>
}
```

COMPONENT 2

```
 const Style = (props) => {
  return(
   <div>
     <h1>{`Please ${props.ojb.text}`}</h1>
     <Button> {`Please ${props.ojb.text}`} </Button> 
  </div> 
)
```

Quick example of what I am expecting:

COMPONET1:

```
 <Icon>{refresh}<span> Refresh the page </span>
 <Button onClick=(send "Refresh the page to COMPONENT2")></Button>
```

COMPONET2:

```
 <h1> Please Refresh the Page </h1>
 <Button> Please Refresh the Page </Button>
```

NOTE: I am using Material-UI to style theses components if that helps.

Again please let me know if there is anything that is confusing about this and if there is anything I can do to clarify. Also, in terms of state management I would prefer not to use redux but I am willing to take feedback on any of this.

Comment: Could you please give more details, on _what_ you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey @FranBran sorry about that I was trying to pass data that was dynamically added from COMPONENT1 to COMPONENT2 but I figured it out using this: https://ozmoroz.com/2018/07/pass-value-to-onclick-react/ turns out I can get the value using ev.currentTarget.value to get the obj.txt from the button in COMPONENT1, pass it to the parent, then pass it as a prop to COMPONENT2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If The COMPONENT2 is a child component of COMPONENT1:**

> Save the clicked button value `obj.text` to the state of COMPONENT1
>   and pass it to COMPONENT2, you can add a function to change that state
>   object on the button's `onClick` event.

**If COMPONENT1 and COMPONENT2 are siblings:**

> 1. Make a function in their parent component to fetch the value from COMPONENT1 using props and pass it to COMPONENT2 from the parent.
> 2. Use Context API or a store. (That would be an overkill if your scenario is simple)

And most importantly Welcome to React and Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out using this: https://ozmoroz.com/2018/07/pass-value-to-onclick-react/ particularly the ev.currentTarget.value to get the obj.txt that was dynamically rendered in COMPONENT1 then it looks like I used the second method you mentioned of getting the value from COMPONENT1, then passing it to the parent then passing it back down to COMPONENT2. I'm not sure how to use Context API yet but I'm from all the info I've been seeing online I think I'll need to when I refactor the code lol. Thanks again for the help!